# Turning Gabor Image Into Binary Image

Tags: matlab, gabor-filter

Currently I am doing a project that involves in extracting a fundus image. I am now (sort of) successful on achieving the Gabor image and now I am trying to turn it into a binary image based from the Gabored output.

My code are listed below:

```
%% Open all/selected fundus image from folder; Source: DIARETDB0
...
retG = retImg(:,:,2);   % Green Channel

%% Morphological Preprocessing - Gabor Filter
lambda = 8;
theta = 0;
psi = [0 pi/2];
gamma = 1.5;
sigma = 3;
bw = 1;
N = 12;
img_in = im2double(retG);
img_out = zeros(size(img_in,1), size(img_in,2), N);
orientation = {};
for n = 1:N
    gb = gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(1),lambda,theta,sigma)...
        + 1i * gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(2),lambda,theta,sigma);
    img_out(:,:,n) = imfilter(img_in, gb, 'symmetric');
    theta = theta + ((n-1)*pi/12);
end
img_out_disp = sum(abs(img_out).^2, 3).^0.5;
img_out_disp = img_out_disp./max(img_out_disp(:));
% Making it binary
bwImg = imbinarize(img_out_disp, 'global'); % Here I am using Otsu's
```

There's seems to be a problem for the result of bwImg (the binary of Gabor output) that it's not as close as I hoped for. I wanted to extract the retina feature, but in the binary image result, much of the retina roots aren't visible (some only made of specs). Thus the question, is there something that I miss or wrong in making of the program?

The images:

[image: Green Fundus Image]

[image: Gabor Output]

[image: Binary Image]

Comment: You can put your images on imgur (or your favorite image sharing site) and add the link to your question. Somebody will likely come along and edit the actual image into your question for you.

Comment: @beaker do I neee to post the links in the comments or should I edit my post above?

Comment: Always edit clarifications and updates into the question itself. It's easier for everyone to see all of the information at once that way. I *thought* they had made it so that new users could use the "insert image" button in edit and it would post a link rather than the image, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @beaker yes, they did make that so the low rep user still can upload images. But when I made the post, there's something wrong so it sorta prevents me on posting images... But now, I've edited it, there's links toward said images...